# Stop image expanding in multiline table row? #2

Tags: ios, iphone, image, row, multiline

[Ok I've had to ask this question again as the first time I was unregistered, and I can't seem to register and link my fb id to that account/or give feedback on my question otherwise! Any way here's the original question, and extra info - original url: [Stop image expanding in multiline table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569492/iosstop-image-expanding-in-multiline-table-row) ]

I'm having problems implementing a table row that allows text to wrap to multiple lines, and also has an image on the left, and a disclosure accessory on the right.

The multiline text is fine but the imageView expands to the right when there is more than one line of text. I want images in all rows to be the same size. I've tried setting the autoresizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingNone but this doesn't seem to work.. Do I need to use the contentView, or a nib file?

Any help/example code appreciated!

EXTRA: HaveYouMetPrabu's answer to my original question kinda worked - but so did my current code UNTIL I changed the row height in heightForRowAtIndex path for rows with more than one line of text (even using an autoresizingMask of UIViewAutoresizingNone) - then the image expands to the right. So I think the solution needs to include both the cellForRow.. & heightForRow.. methods. My current heightForRow.. implementation is probably too simple just switching between 2 fixed row heights depending on the text length..?